# Помогите найти ошибку в коде на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, jquery

Написал программу по выводу погоды, но не работает кнопка.

`HTML` код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Погода</title>
    <script src="eel.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <input id="location" type="text" placeholder="Введите назавание страны и города..."
    required="" value="Нью-Йорк, США">
    <button id="show">Узнать погоду</button>

    <div class="info"></div>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    async function display_weather(){
        let place = document.getElementById('location').value;
        let res = await eel.get_weather(place)
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = res;
    }
    jQuery ('#show').on('click', function(){
        display_weather();
    });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

`Python` код:

```
import eel
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM("d8c8ffd64019538a34c601513e921203")


@eel.expose
def get_weather(place):
    mgr = owm.weather_manager()
    assert isinstance(mgr.weather_at_place, place)
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
    w = observation.weather()
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']
    return "В городе " + place + " сейчас " + str(temp) + " градусов!"


eel.init("web")
eel.start("main.html", size=(700, 700))
```

Выдает такую ошибку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код это текст, а не изображение.

Comment: а где вы здесь код на джаве увидели?

Comment: Прошу прощения. Первый раз задаю вопрос на этой платформе

Comment: Выложите пожалуйста код `html` файла, чтобы можно воспроизвести у себя

Comment: Полностью выложите код. Не видно Вашей кнопки в коде

Comment: Покажите что внутри `eel.js` т.к. и там может быть ошибка тем более если вы сами писали её.

Comment: кнопка как раз у вас работает. у вас дальше не работает. если вы используете в файле eel.js jquery, будет правильнее его подключить после jquery

Comment: Попробуйте `eel.init` поместить перед `@eel.expose`

Comment: Павел, не помогло

Comment: Попробуйте переписать функцию `get_weather` таким образом: [ссылка](https://ideone.com/XxTakA) у меня вроде работает

Comment: Павел, при выполнении программы все равно не выводит погоду